# MNIST Dataset Structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, mnist

I have downloaded a code that implements a genetic algorithm. Its using a default data set `mnist`. I want to change the default dataset 'mnist' but at the same time I want to know the structure of the dataset so that I can format my data to the way `mnist` does it. I also wanted to know for example, if I already formatted my data `my_own_data_set`, will it be valid to feed in the function call `network.train(my_own_data_set)`? What data type does the function `train.network` accepts?

```
"""Entry point to evolving the neural network. Start here."""
import logging
from optimizer import Optimizer
from tqdm import tqdm

# Setup logging.
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='log.txt'
)

def train_networks(networks, dataset):
    """Train each network.

    Args:
        networks (list): Current population of networks
        dataset (str): Dataset to use for training/evaluating
   """
   pbar = tqdm(total=len(networks))
   for network in networks:
       network.train(dataset)
       pbar.update(1)
       pbar.close()

   def get_average_accuracy(networks):
       """Get the average accuracy for a group of networks.

   Args:
       networks (list): List of networks

   Returns:
       float: The average accuracy of a population of networks.

   """
   total_accuracy = 0
   for network in networks:
       total_accuracy += network.accuracy

   return total_accuracy / len(networks)

   def generate(generations, population, nn_param_choices, dataset):
       """Generate a network with the genetic algorithm.

   Args:
       generations (int): Number of times to evole the population
       population (int): Number of networks in each generation
       nn_param_choices (dict): Parameter choices for networks
       dataset (str): Dataset to use for training/evaluating

   """
   optimizer = Optimizer(nn_param_choices)
   networks = optimizer.create_population(population)

   # Evolve the generation.
   for i in range(generations):
       logging.info("***Doing generation %d of %d***" %
                 (i + 1, generations))

       # Train and get accuracy for networks.
       train_networks(networks, dataset)

       # Get the average accuracy for this generation.
       average_accuracy = get_average_accuracy(networks)

       # Print out the average accuracy each generation.
       logging.info("Generation average: %.2f%%" % (average_accuracy * 100))
       logging.info('-'*80)

       # Evolve, except on the last iteration.
       if i != generations - 1:
           # Do the evolution.
           networks = optimizer.evolve(networks)

    # Sort our final population.
    networks = sorted(networks, key=lambda x: x.accuracy, reverse=True)

    # Print out the top 5 networks.
    print_networks(networks[:5])

def print_networks(networks):
    """Print a list of networks.

    Args:
         networks (list): The population of networks

    """
    logging.info('-'*80)
    for network in networks:
        network.print_network()

def main():
    """Evolve a network."""
    generations = 10  # Number of times to evole the population.
    population = 20  # Number of networks in each generation.
    dataset = 'mnist'

    nn_param_choices = {
        'nb_neurons': [64, 128, 256, 512, 768, 1024],
        'nb_layers': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'activation': ['relu', 'elu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid'],
        'optimizer': ['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd', 'adagrad',
                  'adadelta', 'adamax', 'nadam'],
    }

    logging.info("***Evolving %d generations with population %d***" %
             (generations, population))

    generate(generations, population, nn_param_choices, dataset)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "format"?

Comment: @cheersmate -> I mean I want to preprocess my data, the way MNIST is structured in the data set. I want to know MNIST dataset dimensions, the data types it has and so on and so forth.

Comment: So you can check for the array shapes, dtypes etc. first while running it with MNIST, and then add some checks for your own data set?

Comment: @cheersmate but the dataset variable is only a string, See code above. dataset = 'mnist'. I don't know how  network.train(dataset) , extract the data for training. So I could not examine its dimension.

Comment: Do you have the source code to find out what happens internally?

Answer (score 1):

Each line is a string array, 785 strings in quotes, separated by commas.
About 60,000 lines in the training set and 10,000 in the test set.

The line starts with the label of what the rest of the line in a picture of...

"8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", ... "255"...

So the first string item is what digit the image represents, the rest is 784 strings of 0 - 255 that represent the image, which is a 28x28 image that is expressed with the rows end to end as a long array of strings.

string[785] lines, each